How to print in local printer from a remote host?
I am trying to find a way to print in my local printer some labels that I generate in my web. These labels are saved in a folder of my remote host. So I want to be able to send them to print in my local printer.
I have tried something like this
    public function printer()
    {
        $pdfFiles = [
            "path/to/my/folder/file1.pdf",
        ];

        $sumatraPath = 'path/to/AppData/Local/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe';
        
        $timeLapse = 5;
        
        foreach ($pdfFiles as $pdfFilePath) {

            $command = "\"$sumatraPath\" -print-to-default -silent \"$pdfFilePath\"";
            
            exec($command, $output, $return_var);
        
            if ($return_var === 0) {
                echo "Print job for $pdfFilePath sent successfully.\n";
            } else {
                echo "Failed to send print job for $pdfFilePath.\n";
            }
        
            // Sleep for the specified time lapse
            sleep($timeLapse);
        }
    }

This code works perfect in local, but not from remote server because I have no SumatraPDF app in my server and also I think I cant see the printer from the server.

Correct, you can't see the printer from a remote server. You could print from PHP to a network printer, if that printer is in the same network as the PHP server. If the PHP server is on the public internet and the network printer is on a private LAN, you'll need a more complex, de-coupled architecture to be able to pass jobs to it. Or you could consider paying for one of the many "cloud print" type of services which say they can solve this problem for you. And yes you'll also need to install the Sumatra tool in your php server.

The courier companies here solve this problem for their packing labels by running a small agent on the local computer that polls the server for print jobs. You'd need to create some Windows native program to do that, along with some server side code to pass out the print jobs and delete them once they're printed

Just consider this: If it was possible at all to print to a local printer from a website, without the user installing something or giving very explicit permissions, all the printers all over the world would be printing all the time. So it should be difficult to do this. One way of printing locally is to show the content of what you want to print in the browser, either as HTML or as a PDF, and then present the user with a print button. The other solution was just presented by Tangentially Perpendicular.
